# Websphere - Using direct JNDI lookup and JAAS Login Module

Tags: websphere, jndi, jaas

I have Websphere Application Server version 7.0, running on Windows.
I created a JAAS Login Module that implements the javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule interface and created a data source that uses this login module (under Mapping-Configuration alias). Since this data source should get the credentials for the connection from the login module, there are no authentication alias configured on the data source.

I want to use this data source on my application, but my application uses direct JNDI lookup for the data source. According to [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/rdat_jnditips.html) article, when using direct JNDI lookup, websphere creates a default resource-reference that is configured with res-auth=application. Since the res-auth is application my login module is never invoked, but I get a logon denied error because the "Component-Managed Authentication Alias" is empty.
I tried to create a resource reference manually with res-auth=Container but it didn't help.

Is there any way to change the default res-auth to be Container?
Is there any way to make a login module work when the res-auth is set to Application?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rdat_jnditips.html) seems to be the same article as the one you've linked, but a little change in wording seems to have made it more understandable, at least for me. I think you should use the _indirect jndi name_ instead of direct lookup with jdbc/xxx name. Quoting, _retain the java:comp/env prefix. An indirect name makes any resource-reference data associated with the application available to the connection management runtime, to better manage resources based on the res-auth, ..._

Answer (score 0):

Go to your datasource >> security settings >> select your jaas login module for both `Component-managed authentication alias` & `Container-managed authentication alias`

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

u can change res-auth in web.xml file to container, so it will use container managed authenication alias.